# .NET Core mixed F# and C# project Intellisense not working

Tags: c#, macos, visual-studio-code, f#, mono

#### Problem

Given:

- macOS 10.13.6
- VSCode 1.40.1

  - C# package (powered by Omnisharp) 1.21.7
  - Ionide-fsharp 4.3.1
- Mono 6.4.0.198 (`mono --version`) (installed via `brew cask install mono-mdk` or installed via the official macOS package)
- MSBuild 16.3.0 (`msbuild -version`)

I seem to be unable to get intellisense working on VS Code in a project that has to use F# from C#. I have a project in F# and one in C#. And the C# one has a reference to the F# one (to use some of the symbols contained in it).

#### Everything runs and builds correctly

What I did is this:

- `dotnet add reference` the F# project to the C# project
- `dotnet restore` the solution that contains both
- `dotnet build`
- `dotnet run`

And everything works fine on the command line.

On the other hand on VSCode I get "missing reference" errors for symbols defined in the F# project.

#### What have I tried?

I tried every combination of the following sets:

1. Install [Mono 6.4.0](https://www.mono-project.com/download/stable/) (Visual Studio channel)
2. Install [Mono 6.4.0](https://www.mono-project.com/download/stable/) (Stable channel)
3. Install Mono from homebrew (`brew install mono`)
4. Install Mono from homebrew (`brew cask install mono-mdk`)

and:

1. Set `"omnisharp.useGlobalMono": "always"` in my `settings.json` for VS Code
2. Set `"omnisharp.useGlobalMono": "auto" in my`settings.json` for VS Code

Between each attempt I have:

- Cleaned all `bin` and `obj` folders from every project
- Uninstalled other versions of Mono and MSBuild

#### References

I've read the following references but none of the solutions worked:

- https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/1623
- https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-roslyn/issues/1008
- https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/371
- https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/2075

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither OmniSharp nor Ionide recognize or handle mixed C#/F# solutions. Doing so would be an enormous amount of work - the equivalent machinery in Visual Studio is built by a fully staffed team, something open source plugins cannot afford to do.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing settings for F# Extension, "Fsac Runtime" to "Net"
or "Mono" can't remember ... don;t have a Mac right now

It did it for me few days ago

[image]

Comment: The options I have are `netcore` and `net`. It was set to `netcore`. I set it to `net` and I get "Couldn't start client F#" when restarting. Moreover the errors on the C# side remain. Thanks for the attempt :)

Comment: see you have set $MONO_PATH (https://www.mono-project.com/archived/best_practices/#mono_path).
I have to restart vscode every now and then in Linux and osx for the c# project to pickup the changes
Always restart vscode between changes